# Scaling pixel values using Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question or isn't clear enough. But I will try to be as clear and focussed on the problem I currently have. So I am in the process of building an astronomy simulation that will model the brightness changes of stars over time. The image itself is an array storing the corresponding pixel value for each pixel. This is the code I currently have to do this job:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
import os
import csv

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('ngc_3201_V_stack no label (2).fits')
image_data = fits.getdata(image_file)
squareImg = image_data[79:1844, 183:1948]

coord_data = pd.read_csv('test coords.csv', header=0)
X = coord_data['Pixel X'].tolist()
Y = coord_data['Pixel Y'].tolist()

with open('more_stars_test.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  Scales = list(reader)
  Scales.pop(0)

for lists in Scales:
    lists.pop(0)

# setting output dir
outputDir = r'C:\Users\me\Downloads\10_stars_test'
os.chdir(outputDir)

# hardcoding variables
dimension = 1765
radius = 5

print("Output dir: " + outputDir)

# loop through each frame
for frame in range(0, len(Scales)):
    # get current frame number
    frameNum = int(frame)
    print("Starting " + str(frameNum), end="... ")

    # scales for each star per frame
    scales = [float(x) for x in Scales[frame]]
    print(scales)

    # loop through each star
    for star in range(0, len(Scales[0])):
        # create coordinate grid circulating around each star position
        a, b = Y[star], X[star]  # (y,x)
        x, y = np.ogrid[-a:dimension - a, -b:dimension - b]

        # create mask based on those coordinates
        mask = (x ** 2) + (y ** 2) <= (radius ** 2)
        invertedMask = np.invert(mask)
        maskedStar = squareImg * mask
        starRemoved = squareImg * invertedMask

        # scale brightness according to scales
        print(scales[star])
        scaledMaskedStar = maskedStar * float(scales[star])
        scaledMaskedStar[(1 < scaledMaskedStar) & (scaledMaskedStar <= 120)] = 120

        # export final frame with corrected star brightness
        finalFrame = scaledMaskedStar + starRemoved

    # save file with all stars corrected
    print("Saving frame number " + str(frameNum))
    fileName = os.path.join(outputDir, f'frame_{frameNum}.png')
    plt.imsave(fileName, finalFrame, cmap='gray', vmin=78.791, vmax=528.5)
```

As a bit of an explanation, to coordinates csv file holds the pixel coordinates to each star so i can build a mask for each star, and the scaling factors csv holds the float value I am multiplying onto the mask to either brighten or dim the star in a given frame. Each row of the scaling factor csv holds the scaling factors for all the stars per frame. That is, cell 1 in row 1has the scaling factor for star 1 in the first frame. Cell 2 in row 2 has the scaling factor for star 2 in the first frame, and so on.

The issue that I am currently having is that the scaling factors are seemingly not being applied to each frame. So I am effectively saving the original image for each frame. I have a lot of print statements scattered throughout my loops to see if there are functions that are simply just not working, and everything appears to be fine at first glance. Like each of the scaling factors for each star prints for every frame like it is supposed to. It is just that I am not able to scale the original image properly. If any of this was unclear, I can explain further in the comments. Regardless, any insight on how to tackle this problem is welcome

To re-iterate, the goal of this project is to model the brightness changes of stars over time. So I am expecting to see regions around individual stars in my image get brighter/dimmer with time. Up until this point, I have been playing around with the array indexing to see if that was the issue, but I am left with the same result. I was able to confirm that my code is mostly working with this segment of code

```
print(scales[star])
scaledMaskedStar = maskedStar * float(scales[star])
scaledMaskedStar[(1 < scaledMaskedStar) & (scaledMaskedStar <= 120)] = 120
```

Namely, the scaling factors for each star in any given frame printed out as expected. I believe the issue is the scaling calculation itself and the image not saving properly. However, I am unsure why this is happening

Comment: In your inner loop, you overwrite `finalFrame` every time, so effectively only the last loop iteration has an effect.

Comment: This seems to be the problem exactly. I just rendered a sample of the output frames, low and behold, only the last star in the list seems to be pulsating this. Would I work around this by saving the intermediate steps, and just combining the image arrays at the end?

Comment: I would probably do `finalFrame = squareImg.copy()` before the inner loop, and then in the inner loop, `finalFrame[mask] *= float(scales[star])` (assuming there are NumPy arrays). That way you update a copy of the original image by scaling each of the stars.